# Is there a REST API to get subfolders of the workspace in Tosca?

Tags: tosca

I am trying to build a UI based in Angular to retrieve all existing execution lists of Tosca. However, I could not find a REST API that can give the list of folders within a workspace in Tosca. Has anyone tried this route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Search` task on the `project`to find all `ExecutionList`s.
Example:

```
{rest_url}/ToscaCommander/{workspace_name}/object/project/task/Search
```

as a `post` request with the xml payload:

```
<Parameters xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Parameter>
        <Name>tqlString</Name>
        <Type i:nil="true"/>
        <Value>->SUBPARTS:TCFolder[Name=?"Execution"]=>SUBPARTS:ExecutionList</Value>
    </Parameter>
</Parameters>
```

This will give you a list of object ids of the `ExecustionList`s contained in the `Execution` folder of the `project`. You can fetch the objects one by one with this request afterwards:

`{rest_url}/ToscaCommander/{workspace_name}/object/{object_id}`

Credits for this solution go to the development team of ToscaCommander - they provided it.

P.S.: as an answer for your comment:

1. Yes, there is a json equivalent of the body - but you do not need it. Anyway, here is the equivalent:

   `[{
       "Name":"tqlString",
       "Value":"->SUBPARTS:TCFolder[Name=?\"Execution\"]=>SUBPARTS:ExecutionList"
   }]`
2. If you want to get a json response (regardless of the request's payload's format) make sure your `web.config` sets `AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled` to true (which should be the case). Then, in your requests, set the `accept` header accordingly:

   `Accept: application/json`

Comment: is there a json equivalent to the xml payload so i can get json object response?

Comment: I updated my answer to include answer for your two subsequent questions (json payload for requests, json formatted responses)

Comment: thanks Antipodos for being generous with your knowledge... it worked...

Comment: I have a follow up question which I posted in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333467/access-control-allow-origin-accessing-rest-api-of-tosca

Basically, I am calling the tosca rest api from my server and it's giving me "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" exception. Calling it from the rest client app is good but when I am calling it from the web server, it's giving me that error.