# 'access-control-allow-origin' accessing rest api of Tosca

Tags: tosca

I am trying to call Tosca's rest api from my server and it's giving me this exception: 'access-control-allow-origin'. Since I have no control over Tosca's response, is there a way to get around this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is not related to Tosca REST API, rather is a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problem. So, I am assuming your web server and the Tosca REST API server are on different domain. You can basically bypass this problem by allowing cross-origin requests from the web application, by adding the following configuration to the `web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: thanks Atanu. However, I have no control over the web app. But thanks for the info. I will see if i can ask the owner of the web app to update the web.config.

Comment: @arn-arn Just as an update : if your app is hosted in MS Azure cloud, you can do the CORS configuration directly from Azure management portal.

Comment: thanks again Atanu. Unfortunately, that's not our setup. However, i was able to go around it by using java backend which does not throw the pre-flight error. Then my front end just calls my java backend which I can configure myself.